# How to extract value from object inside array?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I cannot get the value of an object inside a list.

I have several objects in API response

```
[
{
    data: {
      productTitle: 'test001',
      serialNumber: 'test001',
      mainImage: [Object],
      secondImage: [Object],
      thirdImage: [Object]
    },
    id: '4d79657f',
    creation_date: '2023-02-22T14:08:05.304Z',
    update_date: '2023-02-22T14:08:05.316Z',
    acceptance: { status: 'NEW' },
    validation: { status: 'VALID' },
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      productTitle: 'test002',
      serialNumber: 'test002',
      mainImage: [Object],
      secondImage: [Object],
      thirdImage: [Object]
    },
    id: 'b82b718c',
    creation_date: '2023-02-22T14:08:05.300Z',
    update_date: '2023-02-22T14:08:05.316Z',
    acceptance: { status: 'NEW' },
    validation: { status: 'VALID' },
    }
  }
]
```

I need to extract id from the object with the productTitle: 'test001'. Could you please help?
...

I tried:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(response)
.filter(({productTitle}) => productTitle === 'test001');
console.log('Result', obj);
```

But got:

Result []

Comment: Btw I don't know what you did but you have some extra brackets in your json.

Comment: You are pointing to obj.productTitle. But it should be obj.data.productTitle